# go compile ebpf libbpfgo program failed: undefined reference to `__builtin_preserve_access_index'

Tags: c, linux, gcc, clang, ebpf

I use libbpfgo and BTF to write an ebpf script.  I success build the .o obj with the following cmd:
`clang -mcpu=v3 -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -D__TARGET_ARCH_x86  -idirafter /usr/lib64/clang/13.0.1/include -idirafter /usr/local/include -idirafter /usr/include -I/opt/code/cpkg/libs -c -target bpf accept-latency-container.bpf.c -o accept-latency-container.bpf.o`

And when I compile the go code with the following cmd:
`CC=gcc CGO_CFLAGS="-I /opt/code/cpkg/libs/bpf" CGO_LDFLAGS="/opt/code/cpkg/libs/bpf/libbpf.a -l bpf" go build -o bin/libbpfgo-prog`.  it fails, and said:

```
CC=gcc CGO_CFLAGS="-I /opt/code/cpkg/libs/bpf" CGO_LDFLAGS="/opt/code/cpkg/libs/bpf/libbpf.a -l bpf" go build -o bin/libbpfgo-prog
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-1672473002/000002.o: in function `kprobe__inet_csk_accept':
accept-latency-container.bpf.c:(kprobe/inet_csk_accept+0x52): undefined reference to `__builtin_preserve_access_index'
/usr/bin/ld: accept-latency-container.bpf.c:(kprobe/inet_csk_accept+0x300): undefined reference to `__builtin_preserve_access_index'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The Go code is here:

```golang
package main

import "C"

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    bpf "github.com/aquasecurity/libbpfgo" // v0.4.5-libbpf-1.0.1
)

func main() {

    bpfModule, _ := bpf.NewModuleFromFile("accept-latency-container.bpf.o")
    defer bpfModule.Close()

    bpfModule.BPFLoadObject()
    prog, _ := bpfModule.GetProgram("kprobe__inet_csk_accept")

    _, _ = prog.AttachKprobe("inet_csk_accept")

    eventsChannel := make(chan []byte)
    rb, _ := bpfModule.InitRingBuf("events", eventsChannel)
    rb.Start()
    for {
        event := <-eventsChannel
        pid := int(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(event[0:4])) // Treat first 4 bytes as LittleEndian Uint32
        comm := string(bytes.TrimRight(event[4:], "\x00")) // Remove excess 0's from comm, treat as string
        fmt.Printf("%d %v\n", pid, comm)
    }

    rb.Stop()
    rb.Close()
}
```

The C code is here:

```c
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>

// 27 buckets for latency, max range is 33.6s .. 67.1s
#define MAX_LATENCY_SLOT 26

// Max number of listening ports we expect to see on the host
#define MAX_PORTS 1024

SEC("kprobe/inet_csk_reqsk_queue_hash_add")
int BPF_KPROBE(kprobe__inet_csk_reqsk_queue_hash_add, struct sock *sk, struct request_sock *req)
{
    // ...
}

SEC("kprobe/inet_csk_accept")
int BPF_KPROBE(kprobe__inet_csk_accept, struct sock *sk)
{
   // ....
}

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

The kernel version and clang version info:

```
# uname -a 
Linux iZuf65u5qmo52bbulj25etZ 5.10.134-14.1.al8.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 25 18:05:52 CST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# clang --version 
clang version 13.0.1 (Red Hat 13.0.1-1.0.1.al8)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

# go env
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/root/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY="git.example.com"
GONOSUMDB="git.example.com"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GOPRIVATE="git.example.com"
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.20.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/opt/code/ebpf/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build96650274=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

My question is:

1. How can I find the `__builtin_preserve_access_index`?
2. Is my kernel version too old or clang version too old  Or something else
3. Is the C compile cmd or go build cmd wrong? if wrong, what is the correct cmd?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your clang version is recent enough and kernel version shouldn't have any impact at this step. Looks like this is your GCC command that fails (`gcc failed: exit status 1`), because as far as I know it doesn't implement the `__builtin_preserve_access_index` built-in. Would this work if you used `clang` instead of `gcc` here? Otherwise I'd suggest checking libbpfgo's project issues to see if there's anything related, or to open an issue to figure out how they're handling the builtin